# Adding comments in wordpress hangs the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the latest version ( as today) of wordpress on my linux 32-bit machine with xampp installed. The wordpress installation is fresh and the only thing that I did is I tried adding comments on the sample page.

When I write comment and click submit, the browser keeps on loading the page (hanged) saying "waiting for localhost" and after 1-2 minutes the page goes white. Though when I look into the dashboard, the comments are there.

On asking google, I found [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-entering-comment-hangs-at-wp-comments-postphp) , but its including some `xcache` and I don't what's that or even if its related to me. Has anyone solved this problem before? Any solutions?

Comment: It happend to me once, I tried to make  the JavaScript delete some elements/values in some inputs/form. What cause the page to hang for a response.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales : But I haven't made any changes to wordpress. Its a fresh install.

Comment: can you do the install again ?, maybe something went wrong in the process.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales : I tried that also. I even installed a lower version but same problem. I tried on a different PC, but same problem.